# How to change core.autocrlf in Gitlab used in the merge operation?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

When we merge locally we use the `core.autocrlf=true` setting to correctly handle the line ending differences.

How to control the `core.autocrlf` setting when merging **directly** from the Gitlab's web interface?

We observed that some files appear to be entirely changed in the `Changes` tab and it might be related to this setting.

P.S. all developers have locally the correct `core.autocrlf` setting.

Comment: If all developers have `core.autocrlf=true`, the repository should only ever see unix newlines and gitlab shouldn't need to handle anything. Do you really have it set consistently?

Answer (score 3):

The only correct `core.autocrlf` setting all developers should have locally is:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Any eol conversion should be managed exclusively [through `.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_effects), which is versioned, part of your sources, and can be set for a particular subset of files.
As opposed to a `core.autocrlf` local setting, which is controlled by each user, and apply to *every file* (even binary ones)

This principle is reflected in GitLab issues like [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 21431](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21431)

> I think the proposed solution here is for both the Web IDE and the Single File Editor to properly support the use of a `.gitattributes` file when present.

However, as shown in [gitlab-org/gitlab issue 14391](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14391), this (the `.gitattributes` file) is still not supported by the WebEditor when doing a merge request.

So for now, eol are not properly managed when the MR is done entirely on GitLab side.